# Creating virtual harddrive from physical Windows 2000 server installation

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, windows-server-2000

I have found lots of guides on how to create a virtual image of a win xp or newer windows, but it eludes me how I can do that with win 2000 server. Anyone have any good input here? I was hoping to end up using virtualbox.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to install a virtual machine from scratch or if you would rather convert a currently physical machine to a virtual one?

Comment: I want to convert a currently physical machine to a virtual one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VMware Converter version 3 is supported for 2000.  Then you may be able to convert from their format to a VirtualBox format.

I run plenty of 2000 VMware images but cannot remember how I made them.  Too long ago and too many other servers later.

Comment: Interesting, I am giving that a whirl. Seems it should be entirely doable to convert to vhd after such a process. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I managed to create a VMDK backup of the win 2000 server harddrive. Then I used the 'vmdk2vhd' tool to convert it to VHD, then I loaded it in VirtualBox. It does start to boot, but it freezes before it loads the windows logo. I tried this on two different computers with different hardware, the same thing happened. I am puzzled as to what the cause could be.

Comment: I booted with the win2k cd, used recovery console to fixboot and fixmbr, no difference. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Have you tried having a fiddle with the ACPI settings? Windows can sometimes be a little finicky about being uprooted from its original hardware.

Comment: Awesome, this worked! Just enabled IO APIC, that was all I had to do. Thank you Novex! :]

Comment: I'm all for open source, but VMware Converter does a good job. Kudos to Keith.

Answer (score 3):

You should read up on the Virtualbox documentation on [Migrating Windows Machines](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows).

On creating the LowLevel Image mentioned in the above document I would read up on [Imaging your Hard Drive using `dd`](http://www.linuxweblog.com/dd-image)

Comment: The 2nd link there might be helpful, although it's going to be hard to do. It's a server located in a server room with lots of security clearances needed, so if I was to hook up an extra drive to it that would certainly take some effort. But thank you, if it comes down to that I might have to attempt it. Hopefully some other option will come up though, I do have remote access to it.

Comment: The problem which prevents current software from working with win2k is that most tools uses Windows' Volume Snapshot feature which is present since WinXP

Comment: Exactly, therein lies the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) by SysInternals
The difference between Disk2vhd and other physical-to-virtual tools is that you can run Disk2vhd on a system that’s online

Answer (score 0):

I believe Symantec's Ghost product can make images that can be run by VMWare